# Calibration using predict_proba vs class_weight

Tags: machine-learning, python, classification, scikit-learn, random-forest

I am making a Random Forest Classifier to determine whether a sentence is "positive" (1), "negative"(-1) or "neutral"(0).

However, I prefer having false negative than false positive, that is, I prefer saying that a sentence is neutral even if it's not than to say that a sentence is positive when it's neutral, a fortiori if it's negative.

So I use `predict_proba`, with something like:

```py
def my_pred(rfc, X, weight=0.5):
  res = rfc.predict_proba(X) 
  if res[0]>weight: return -1
  elif res[2]>weight: return 1
  return 0
```

But I wonder if I can make such things (give more importance to the neutral class) using `class_weight`? Would it be better?

Answer (score 5):

There are several options for you:

- `class_weight` should boost the loss function towards the preferred class. This option is supported by various estimators, including [`sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html),

[`sklearn.svm.SVC`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html), [`sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html), and others. Note there's no theoretical limit to the weight ratio, so even if 1 to 100 isn't strong enough for you, you can go on with 1 to 500, etc.

- You can also select the decision threshold very low during the cross-validation to pick the model that gives highest recall (though possibly low precision). The recall close to `1.0` effectively means `false_negatives` close to `0.0`, which is what to want. For that, use [`sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html) and [`sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve`](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_curve.html) functions:

  ```
    y_scores = cross_val_predict(classifier, x_train, y_train, cv=3,

                                 method="decision_function")



    precisions, recalls, thresholds = precision_recall_curve(y_train, y_scores)
  ```

  If you plot the `precisions`  and `recalls` against the `thresholds`, you should see the picture like this:

  [image: precision-recall-tradeoff]

  After picking the best threshold, you can use the raw scores from `classifier.decision_function()` method for your final classification.

Finally, try not to over-optimize your classifier, because you can easily end up with a trivial const classifier (which is obviously never wrong, but is useless).

As said there are 2 stages to make this Tuning: in the model training stage (like custom weights) and the prediction stage (like lowering the decision threshold).

Another tuning for the model-training stage is [using a recall scorer](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LogisticRegression.html). you can use it in your grid-search cross-validation ([GridSearchCV](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.svm.SVC.html)) for tuning your classifier with the best hyper-param towards high recall.

GridSearchCV **scoring** parameter can either accepts the **'recall'** string or the function [**recall_score**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.ensemble.RandomForestClassifier.html).

Since you're using a binary classification, both options should work out of the box, and call **recall_score** with its default values that suits a binary classification:

- average: 'binary' (i.e. one simple recall value)
- pos_label: 1 (like numpy's True value)

Should you need to custom it, you can wrap an existing scorer, or a custom one, with [**make_scorer**](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.cross_val_predict.html), and pass it to the **scoring** parameter.